# Return view in json value in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, view, return

```
if($listing != null) {  
    return \Response::json($listing);//return propertyees matching the search parameters
} else { 
    return \Response::json(array(["message"=>"Sorry no properties found matching your search criteria. Please try again."]),200);           
}
```

Return view in json

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish and what you tried already. Can you be more specific?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
if($listing != null) { 
   return response()->json(['result' => $listing]);//return propertyees matching the search parameters
 }else {
   return response()->json((["message"=>"Sorry no properties found matching your search criteria. Please try again."]),200);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($listing != null) { 
  return response()->json($listing);
 }
```